# Facebook auto-reauth

Tags: facebook, curl, oauth, access-token, facebook-access-token

I wrote a python script that runs on a cron job on my server that posts to my facebook account for me using my own facebook app. Unfortunately, every couple months, I get:

```
Response: {u'error': {u'message': u'Error validating access token: Session has expired...', u'code': 190, u'type': u'OAuthException', u'error_subcode': 463}}
```

Every time this occurs, I have to log into facebook, get a new code -> access token.

I'd like to fully automate this so that I can get a new access token without ever logging into facebook. What's the best way to do this?

I'd prefer a way to do this without storing my password on my server or accessing facebook via curl (which would be a hack), but--worst comes to worst--I suppose I could just login to facebook with curl to get the code -> access token.

Please don't tell me to use offline_access (as most of my searches show). That's been deprecated.

TIA!

edit: here's how I currently re-auth (this requires me to log into facebook):

1. log into facebook in browser
2. visit in browser: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=publish_actions
3. extract $code returned from facebook
4. curl "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=YYY&code=$code"
5. store updated access_token that's returned from facebook

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly how it is supposed to be. There is no way (anymore) to get a User Access Token that is valid forever. No app should be allowed to use a Token of a User who did not open the App in more than 60 days.

One solution is to create a Facebook Page and use an Extended Page Access Token, because those are valid forever. Here are a couple of links with all the information you need:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to update a Facebook Page. I know this isn't supported by facebook, but I'm sure someone has figured out a way around it.

What's the best way to log into a facebook account from a server? curl? what about [fbcmd](http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/)? Are there other options for a headless server to login to facebook that I'm unaware of?

Comment: IF there is a way around it, then it´s 100% illegal and should be reported to facebook as security issue ;) - else the whole change to short living access tokens would be pretty much void.